# How to refresh or move pin when user gets current location

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I am working on an application which use user location updates, I have  got the current latitude and longitude and display the current location of the user and annotate the pin, However I need help regarding moving a pin when user changes his location or when user moves and get new latitude and longitude the pin should also move to that position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show the current location, you could just set `showsUserLocation` to YES and let the map show the blue dot for you.

If you want to show your own annotation instead and have it move automatically, implement [`setCoordinate:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MKAnnotation/setCoordinate%3a) in the class that implements the `MKAnnotation` protocol.

Then when the coordinates change, update the annotation's coordinate and the map view will automatically (via KVO) move the annotation's view/pin.

You could also remove the annotation and create a new one at the new location but that can result in flicker.

If you are using Core Location to get location updates, you would update the annotation's coordinates in the `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` delegate method.

Comment: Hi Anna, thank you for this useful answer, for my case i invoke the google-maps API to trace the itinerary between two points and this API is charged of all stuff, havn't i any intervention to refresh the blue dot when the user move on? thanx

Comment: @Malek, if your app is switching to the Maps app, then you have no control over it as far as I know.  If you are using a Google map on an html page that uses the JavaScript API, you might be able make JS calls to do that but I've never tried that.

Comment: @Anna : ok to implement setCoordinate into the class that implements the MKAnnotation, but how do you replace the MKUserLocation annotation that is inserted on the map by the mapView by this one ? And later, when - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)aMapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation is called, it's a MKUserLocation that is given, so it's coordinates should already be updated, don't they ?

Comment: @Oliver, what this answer says is if you want to use your own annotation, keep map view's showsUserLocation at **NO** and use _Core Location Manager's_ didUpdateToLocation delegate method instead to update your custom user location annotation's coordinates.  MKUserLocation would no longer be used or come up.

Comment: @Anna : ok, I've done that.  I have kept the blue dot on the screen for comparison, and I can see that the pin does not automatically move. I add the `self.customAnnotation` if nil in `didUpdateUserLocation` (works), then `[self.customUserLocationAnnotation setUserCoordinate:newLocation.coordinate];` in `didUpdateToLocation:fromlocation:` (does not move the pin on the screen)